# Full Groovy List not being passed to python script

Tags: python-2.7, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Within my Jenkins Pipeline I have a a Groovy List, as a value in a Map, and I want to pass the full list into a Python script. However, only the first element of the list is being passed in, rather than the full list.

My map `orderedScripts` contains key values from 1 - 11 and the values of those keys are lists.

Groovy Code

```
orderedScripts.each { key, value -> 
    echo "${value}"
    bat "C:\\Python25\\python.exe D:\\CI2\\App.py ${value}"
}
```

Python Code

```
import sys

scripts_list = sys.argv[1]
print scripts_list
```

Output (Can only see the first element of the list)

```
[C:\Program Files (x86)\Path\To\Script\myapp.sql,
```

I notice that it stops after when first it reaches the first comma , and doesn't append the closing right bracket to finish the list.

From the python print statement I can see that the list isn't being passed in correctly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when I pass in the `${value}` list within Groovy

** Edit **

Output from orderedScripts.dump()

```
<java.util.LinkedHashMap@79d8b367 head=8=["C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreAPI\0.DBA\8.Packages\available_positions_api.pak", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreAPI\0.DBA\8.Packages\core_document_utility.pak", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreDBA\0.DBA\8.Packages\codb_email_to_core.bod"] tail=8=["C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreAPI\0.DBA\8.Packages\available_positions_api.pak", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreAPI\0.DBA\8.Packages\core_document_utility.pak", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreDBA\0.DBA\8.Packages\codb_email_to_core.bod"] accessOrder=false table=[8=["C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreAPI\0.DBA\8.Packages\available_positions_api.pak", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreAPI\0.DBA\8.Packages\core_document_utility.pak", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreDBA\0.DBA\8.Packages\codb_email_to_core.bod"], null] entrySet=[8=["C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreAPI\0.DBA\8.Packages\available_positions_api.pak", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreAPI\0.DBA\8.Packages\core_document_utility.pak", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI2\workspace\Core\Core\CoreDBA\0.DBA\8.Packages\codb_email_to_core.bod"]] size=1 modCount=1 threshold=1 loadFactor=0.75 keySet=null values=null>
```

Comment: Could you also add a result of `println orderedScripts.dump()` to your question so we can investigate what initial map looks like?

Comment: Encode that list in a format passable to python (either pass each element of that list as parameter (so sys.argv contains all of them) or use something like JSON.  Also make sure, that you do (or don't) use proper quoting with that `bat` call -- depending in what it wants.  I for my part would do `(["python", "script.y"] + values).execute()`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that..

Comment: Well it looks like I was incorrectly picking it up within the python script. Slice section changed in the sys.argv call to     scripts_list = sys.argv[1:]   instead of scripts_list = sys.argv[1]    -   Thanks for your help on this!